# NullPointerException при создании экземпляра родительского класса

Tags: java, наследование

Я новичок в джава. Не могу понять, почему возникает следующая ошибка.

У меня есть абстрактный класс `Figure`. В нем есть метод нахождения площади `public abstract double area()`

```java
public abstract class Figure {

    public abstract double area();
}
```

Есть класс `Point`, описывающий положение точки на координатной оси параметрами x и y:

```java
public class Point {
    private double x;
    private double y;

    public Point(final double x, final double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

Есть класс `Triangle`, наследуемый от `Figure`. В нем заданы поля - три точки `a, b, c` на координатной плоскости. Также в нем есть переопределенный метод `area`, который успешно вычисляет площадь треугольника по формуле Герона.

```
public class Triangle extends Figure {

    Point a;
    Point b;
    Point c;

    Triangle (Point a, Point b, Point c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    public double area() {
        double area;
        double p;

        double x1 = a.getX();
        double x2 = b.getX();
        double x3 = c.getX();
        double y1 = a.getY();
        double y2 = b.getY();
        double y3 = c.getY();

        double q = Math.sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
        double w = Math.sqrt((x1 - x3) * (x1 - x3) + (y1 - y3) * (y1 - y3));
        double e = Math.sqrt((x2 - x3) * (x2 - x3) + (y2 - y3) * (y2 - y3));

        p = (q + w + e) / 2.0;

        area = Math.sqrt(p * (p - q) * (p - w) * (p - e));

        return area;
    }
}
```

И есть класс `Quadrilateral`, наследуемый от `Triangle`. Тут есть четыре точки - вершины углов `a, b, c, d`. В нем тоже есть переопределенный метод `area`, который должен вычислять площадь четырехугольника.

Я хочу рассчитать эту площадь путем сложения площадей двух треугольников с общей стороной-диагональю. То есть, для этого я в методе `area()` создаю экземпляр класса `Triangle`.

```
Triangle tr1 = new Triangle(a, b, c);
```

Но при запуске он выдает на этой строке `NullPointerException`. Почему?

```
public class Quadrilateral extends Triangle {
    Point a;
    Point b;
    Point c;
    Point d;

    Quadrilateral(Point a, Point b, Point c, Point d) {
        super(a, b, c);
        this.d = d;
    }

    public double length (Point start, Point end) {
        return sqrt(Math.pow((start.getX() - end.getX()), 2) + Math.pow((start.getY() - end.getY()), 2));
    }

    @Override
    public double area() {
        Triangle tr1 = new Triangle(a, b, this.c);

        double area1 = tr1.area();
        double area2;

        if (length(d, a) > length(d, b) && length(d, a) > length(d, c)) {
            Triangle tr2 = new Triangle(d,b,c);
            area2 = tr2.area();
            return area1 + area2;
        }
        else if (length(d, c) > length(d, a) && length(d, c) > length(d, b)) {
            Triangle tr2 = new Triangle(d,a,b);
            area2 = tr2.area();
            return area1 + area2;
        }
        else {
            Triangle tr2 = new Triangle(d,a,c);
            area2 = tr2.area();
            return area1 + area2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В этой строчке

```
Triangle tr1 = new Triangle(a, b, this.c);
```

не может возникать `NullPointerException`. A в этой

```
double area1 = tr1.area();
```

может и возникает.

```
public class Quadrilateral extends Triangle {
  //Point a;
  //Point b;
  //Point c;
  Point d;
```

---

> И есть класс Quadrilateral, наследуемый от Triangle.

То есть четырехугольник это треугольник?

---

Что там дальше за бред с проверками длин сторон? Вы пытаетесь учесть случай невыпуклого четырехугольника? Вам это не удалось.

Comment: Видимо, да, четырехугольник - это треугольник. Ты спросишь, а зачем так было сделано? Потому что так надо было!

Comment: Люблю иронию) да, согласен, с наследование от треугольника - чушь) спасибо за комменты

Comment: @ArturVartanyan Очень хорошо. Тогда круг это тоже треугольник.

Answer (score 0):

NullPointerException возникает, так как точки `a, b, c` определены и в папе-треугольнике, и в его четырехугольном потомке, соответственно, после вызова конструктора `Quadrilateral(Point a, Point b, Point c, Point d)` они будут проинициализированы только у папы.

И при создании `Triangle tr1 = new Triangle(a, b, this.c);` в методе `Quadrilateral::area` в `tr1` все точки будут `null`, соответственно при вычислении площади `tr1` будет выброшено исключение.

Если наследование выбрано для вынесения неких общих полей в класс-предок, то не нужно дублировать такие поля в потомках.